# How to remove dot after section letter?

Tags: sectioning

I know this question has been asked multiple times. Unfortunately none of the other solutions actually work.

So heres my code:

`\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\roman{subsubsection}}`

This works for others. This code however compiles to

1.

a.

ii.

Here ist my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, ngerman]{scrartcl}


\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\alph{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\roman{subsubsection}}


\begin{document}


\section{Section heading}    
\subsection{Subsection heading}    
\subsubsection{Subsubsection heading}

\end{document}
```

This drives me insane. Is there something that I'm missing?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It depends on the document class and packages that you're using (which is why we need a MWE). For example, with the KOMA script classes the dot is removed with `numbers=noendperiod` but if you're using another class there may be some other setting.

Comment: I worked with the KOMA script scrartcl and scrreprt. Adding the parameter `numbers=noendperiod` fixed this problem for me! Thank you very much!